# Calendar field increment gives unexpected results

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm working on creating a method to show the difference in time between two dates. To do this, I am using Calendar, and subtracting the dates to receive the remaining number available. However, for some reason, it's returning unexpected results. Here is my method in an extended `Date` class:

```
public String getReadableTimeDifference(Date fromDate, boolean showMilliseconds) {
    String[] result = new String[7];

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(this);
    from.setTime(fromDate);

    // The two dates are correct. using a polymorphic method getReadableTimeDifference(boolean),
    // it supplies this method with the current date. "this" is always a date in the future.
    // Let's say that "this" is a date 10 seconds in the future:
    System.out.println(from.getTime());
    System.out.println(this);

    // Since it's 10 seconds in the future, it will print the same (2016):
    System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " + from.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    // It should subtract the from date (2016) from the existing date (2016)
    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -from.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -from.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -from.get(Calendar.DATE));
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, -from.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -from.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, -from.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -from.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    // It should print "0" (because 2016-2016 = 0) but instead it prints 2.
    System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    int years = Math.abs(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    int months = Math.abs(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    int days = Math.abs(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
    int hours = Math.abs(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    int minutes = Math.abs(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    int seconds = Math.abs(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    int milliseconds = Math.abs(calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    if (years > 0) {
        result[0] = Utilities.prettyNumerate("year", years);
    }

    if (months > 0) {
        result[1] = Utilities.prettyNumerate("month", months);
    }

    if (days > 0) {
        result[2] = Utilities.prettyNumerate("day", days);
    }

    if (hours > 0) {
        result[3] = Utilities.prettyNumerate("hour", hours);
    }

    if (minutes > 0) {
        result[4] = Utilities.prettyNumerate("minute", minutes);
    }

    if (seconds > 0) {
        result[5] = Utilities.prettyNumerate("second", seconds);
    }

    if (milliseconds > 0 && showMilliseconds) {
        result[6] = Utilities.prettyNumerate("millisecond", milliseconds);
    }

    return Utilities.join(Utilities.clean(result), ", ", " and ");
}
```

`prettyNumerate` takes a number and appends an "s" to the end of the supplied string if it's over 1, under -1 or 0. `clean` cleans an array of any null or empty elements. `join` join's an array by a delimiter, and a final delimiter for the last element. The expected outcome should be:

`10 seconds`

But instead it's:

`2 years, 11 months, 31 days and 10 seconds`

Nothing else is being manipulated within this custom date. When I instantiate this custom date, after any custom code is completed I print out `this.getTime()` and it prints out the correct time in milliseconds, which is 10 seconds into the future as it should be.

Comment: This would all be much easier if you'd use the `java.time` API in Java 8 or [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead of the old `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` classes. A `Calendar` is not suitable for storing time **differences**, which is what you seem to want to do with it.

Comment: I'll look into it. But for the sake of the question, it still confuses me as to why 2016-2016 = 2. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just do `calendar.setTimeInMillis(getTime(), fromDate.getTime());`?

Comment: Because a `Calendar` isn't just a bunch of date and time fields; changing one field may also change the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year field in Calendar object of Java is relative to the era. By setting the year to something less or equal to 0 the calendar automatically corrects this by switching the era (from AD to BC or from BC to AD). This behaviour is better known from the other fields. For example, if you set the month to something negative, the year gets decremented accordingly.

Those corrections aren't made individually but rather they are made all at once, usually when you call getTime() to read out the resulting date.

Therefore, if you subtract year 2016 from a date in 2016, it automatically gets corrected to 1st century BC. When you do more subtractions, the time actually reaches 2nd century BC.

As suggested in some comments, you will be better off using Joda time for your usecase.

Comment: Thanks. I understand this now. I'll likely use Java 8's time API.